# Unity Github conflicting dwlt file

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, git-commit, conflict

We develop some game with my friend and sharing code and scenes with GitHub. Everything was fine but after one commit (where I add some new working script and deleted some trash from project) he has a conflict with this dwlt file (as in screenshot 1), but I have everything okay (as in screenshot 2). Project with changes working fine but we have strange conflict here. Can anybody help plz?

[image: Screenshot from friend's Github Desktop]
[image: Screenshot from my Github Desktop with trouble commit]

Comment: You can add this file in the gitignore. You can take the [official unity gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore).

Comment: The conflict is the result of running `git stash`, but as @YannisSauzeau suggests, the file itself probably should never have been committed. Had it not been committed, you and the other guy would not be attempting to merge these things in the first place and hence not having this problem. But note that *removing* the committed file (which is necessary if you're going to ignore it in the future) sets up a problem for at least one of you two: whoever *doesn't* run `git rm --cached` needs to save his file somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same user case illustrated in this [Unity thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/github-doesnt-ignore-the-usersettings-folder-and-the-default-2021-dwlt-file.1217259/) with:

- putting `[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/` in [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore)
- `git rm --cached -r UserSettings/`

That will only remove that folder content from the most recent commit.